# imap_open in php suddenly stopped working reading office 365 mail box from 15 Oct 2022

Tags: php, office365, tls1.2, imap-open

imap_open in php suddenly stopped working reading office 365 mail box from 15 Oct 2022. Talked to a Vendor of Office 365. He adviced to use TLS 1.2. But I have no idea how to use TLS 1.2 in my code.

How to incorporate  TLS 1.2 in the code? The error I am getting is as below:

> Can not authenticate to IMAP server: AUTHENTICATE failed.

```
$username =  $row->email;
$password =  $row->password;

$mailbox = "{outlook.office365.com:993/imap/ssl/authuser=$username}";
$inbox = imap_open($mailbox, $username, $password);


if (!$inbox){
    print imap_last_error();      
}
```

Comment: Do you read the manual of imap_open function...? [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-open.php). There are examples with SSL it seems to me not ..? To see maybe..?

Comment: Note: Microsoft is discontinuing basic authentication for IMAP connections . Check `Oauth IMAP` application (e.g. `https://www.php-imap.com/examples/oauth` )

Comment: This is what @KenLee was referring to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/deprecation-of-basic-authentication-exchange-online and it seems there's way to enable the old way back until the end of year.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the reply. But can anyone give idea of the changes that need to be done in the code that I have posted above.