# IMAP can't authenticate in OUTLOOK OFFICE365

Tags: php, laravel, imap

In Laravel, IMAP (retrieve mail data to store it on my database) work as usual in GMAIL but when I want to connect it with outlook office365 mail it does not work. Can any one please help me? In below I described my outlook office365 settings.

```
IMAP_HOST='outlook.office365.com'
IMAP_PORT=993
IMAP_ENCRYPTION='ssl'
IMAP_VALIDATE_CERT=true
IMAP_USERNAME='my outlook mail'
IMAP_PASSWORD='my outlook mail password'
IMAP_PROTOCOL='imap'
IMAP_AUTHENTICATION="oauth"
```

Webklex\PHPIMAP\Exceptions\ConnectionFailedException
connection setup failed

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74319024/imap-open-in-php-suddenly-stopped-working-reading-office-365-mail-box-from-15-oc may be relevant

Comment: There was also no solution.